# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running JMS consumer

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to run a class I made however I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/jms/Destination

I don't understand why it's not working even when I include the necessary jars in the classpath:

> java consumer1 -cp
>   activemq-all-5.3.2.jar

Comment: Is activemq-all-5.3.2.jar in the same directory as consumer1?

Comment: Have you checked the activemq-all-5.3.2.jar so make sure it's got that class? (might be a corrupt artifact) you can execute 'jar tvf activemq-all-5.3.2.jar' to see.

Comment: I checked it by expanding the jar in eclipse. It is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-cp` option of `java` command should be placed before the class name:

```
java -cp .;activemq-all-5.3.2.jar consumer1
```

Otherwise it's treated as an argument of your `main` method, not as `java`'s argument. Also note that if you specify classpath with `-cp` option, you need to include the current directory in order to run `.class` files from it.

Comment: I did the -cp option before the class name before. The only difference this time is that I added this ".;" what does that mean? To include in the classpath everything in the current folder? I don't understand why I need to do that when there are no dependencies in the current folder.

Comment: @Jeune: When you run `java consumer1`, `consumer1` is a name of class in the classpath. By default classpath is a current directory, so this command will run `consumer1.class` from it. When you use `-cp` option, you override the default classpath, so you need to specify the current folder explicitly in order to run `consumer1.class` from it.

Comment: NOTE: On Linux you need `:` as a separator instead of `;`. Drove me nuts.